# A* Pathfinder in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write an A* pathfinder to learn C++ and am struggling with a specific bug.

These are the features/assumptions of the program:

- The path contains "walls" which cannot be passed
- All paths cost the same value (1)
- Diagonal movement is allowed
- Only one goal

Here is my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>


using Graph = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
using Position = std::tuple<int, int>;
class Node;
using Nodes = std::vector<Node>;


constexpr int WALL_BLOCK = 1;
constexpr int USER_BLOCK = 3;
constexpr int GOAL_BLOCK = 2;


class Node {
    private:
        int row;
        int column;
        Node* parent = nullptr;

        int f = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int h = 0;

    public:
        Node() : row(-1), column(-1) {}
        Node(int row, int column) : row(row), column(column)  {}
        Node(int row, int column, Node *parent) : row(row), column(column) {
            if (this->parent != nullptr && *this->parent == *this) {
                throw "Node cannot be parented to itself";
            }

            this->parent = parent;
        }
        ~Node() {}

        Node* get_parent() const { return this->parent; }
        int get_f() const { return this->f; }
        int get_g() const { return this->g; }
        int get_h() const { return this->h; }
        Position get_position() const { return std::make_tuple(row, column); }

        void set_f(int f) { this->f = f; }
        void set_g(int g) { this->g = g; }
        void set_h(int h) { this->h = h; }

        bool operator==(Node const &node) const {
            return this->row == node.row && this->column == node.column;
        }

        bool operator<(Node const &node) const {
            return this->row < node.row && this->column < node.column;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node const &node);
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node const &node) {
    auto row = node.row;
    auto column = node.column;
    os << "Node(("
        << row << ", "
        << column << "), "
        << node.get_g() << ", "
        << node.get_h() << ", "
        ;

    Node* parent = node.get_parent();

    if (parent != nullptr) {
        os << parent;
    } else {
        os << "nullptr";
    }

    os << ")";

    return os;
}


inline bool is_walkable(Node const &node, Graph const &graph) {
    int column;
    int row;
    std::tie(row, column) = node.get_position();

    return graph[row][column] != WALL_BLOCK;
}


Position get_first_index(Graph const &graph, int block);


Position get_end(Graph const &graph) {
    return get_first_index(graph, GOAL_BLOCK);
}


Position get_first_index(Graph const &graph, int block) {
    for (int row = 0, max = graph.size(); row < max; ++row) {
        auto line = graph[row];
        auto found = std::find(line.begin(), line.end(), block);

        if (found != line.end()) {
            return std::make_tuple(row, found - line.begin());
        }
    }

    return {-1, -1};
}


inline int get_h(Node const &node, Node const &reference) {
    auto node_position = node.get_position();
    auto reference_position = reference.get_position();
    auto node_position_row = std::get<0>(node_position);
    auto node_position_column = std::get<1>(node_position);
    auto reference_position_row = std::get<0>(reference_position);
    auto reference_position_column = std::get<1>(reference_position);

    return (
        std::pow((node_position_row - reference_position_row), 2) +
        std::pow((node_position_column - reference_position_column), 2)
    );
}


Position get_start(Graph const &graph) {
    return get_first_index(graph, USER_BLOCK);
}


Nodes get_children(Node &node, Graph const &graph) {
    Nodes children;

    int row;
    int column;
    std::tie(row, column) = node.get_position();

    for (int row_offset = -1; row_offset < 2; ++row_offset) {
        for (int column_offset = -1; column_offset < 2; ++column_offset) {
            if (row_offset == 0 and column_offset == 0) {
                // (0, 0) will always be `node`. We can't let `node` be a child
                // of itself so we have to `continue` here
                //
                continue;
            }

            Graph::size_type node_row = row + row_offset;
            Graph::size_type node_column = column + column_offset;

            if (node_row >= graph.size()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (node_column >= graph[node_row].size()) {
                continue;
            }

            children.push_back({
                static_cast<int>(node_row),
                static_cast<int>(node_column),
                &node
            });
        }
    }

    return children;
}


Nodes trace(Node const &node) {
    Node* parent = node.get_parent();
    Nodes path;
    std::set<Node> seen;

    while (parent != nullptr) {
        auto parent_node = *parent;
        if (std::find(seen.begin(), seen.end(), parent_node) != seen.end()) {
            // If this happens, `parent` is already in `path`. To avoid
            // a cyclic loop from happening, we will break out, instead.
            //
            break;
        }

        seen.insert(parent_node);
        path.push_back(parent_node);
        parent = parent->get_parent();
    }

    return path;
}


Nodes a_star(Graph const &graph, Node const &user, Node const &goal) {
    Nodes open_list {user};
    Nodes closed_list;

    while (open_list.size() != 0) {
        Node current_node = open_list[0];
        unsigned int current_index = 0;

        for (int index = 0, max = open_list.size(); index < max; ++index) {
            auto node = open_list[index];
            if (node.get_f() < current_node.get_f()) {
                current_node = node;
                current_index = index;
            }
        }

        if (current_node == goal) {
            auto path = trace(current_node);
            std::reverse(path.begin(), path.end());
            return path;
        }

        open_list.erase(open_list.begin() + current_index);
        closed_list.push_back(current_node);

        auto children = get_children(current_node, graph);
        for (auto &child : children) {
            if (std::find(closed_list.begin(), closed_list.end(), child) != closed_list.end()) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!is_walkable(child, graph)) {
                continue;
            }

            child.set_g(child.get_parent()->get_g() + 1);
            child.set_h(get_h(child, goal));
            child.set_f(child.get_g() + child.get_h());

            bool add = true;
            for (auto const &open : open_list) {
                if (child == open && child.get_g() > open.get_g()) {
                    add = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (add) {
                open_list.push_back(child);
            }
        }
    }

    return {};
}


int main() {
    Graph graph = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    };

    int start_row = 0;
    int start_column = 0;
    std::tie(start_row, start_column) = get_start(graph);

    int end_row = 0;
    int end_column = 0;
    std::tie(end_row, end_column) = get_end(graph);

    auto user = Node(start_row, start_column);
    auto goal = Node(end_row, end_column);

    std::cout << user << std::endl;
    std::cout << goal << std::endl;

    auto nodes = a_star(graph, user, goal);

    std::cout << "Path: [";
    for (auto const &node : nodes) {
        std::cout << "("
            << std::get<0>(node.get_position())
            << ", "
            << std::get<1>(node.get_position())
            << "), ";
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on my computer, I get this output:

```
Node((1, 1), 0, 0, nullptr)
Node((1, 6), 0, 0, nullptr)
Path: [(1, 6), ]
```

`Path:` should have returned a full list starting from `(1, 1)` to the goal, `(1, 6)` But instead of `[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 4), (3, 5), (2, 6), (1, 6), ]`. we got `[(1, 6), ]`. I think the reason for this is because `current_node` contains itself as a parent. So `trace` breaks early to avoid a cyclic loop. And that's why there's only one in the output. It's weird that any Node would have itself as a parent because the constructor throws an exception if that happens.

In fact on my machine, every parent of every single node is the same address, `0x7fffffff9140`, which shouldn't be happening.

My only guess to this is that `current_node` is being initialized in the while loop so maybe even though the Node position / f / g / h are changing, the pointer in memory never does. So all the nodes end up getting the same parent that way.

That may or may not be the issue but either way, I'm not sure how to fix it. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line using the debugger? That's usually better than just _guessing_.

Comment: The logic of the a_star seemed like it *should* work, even in the debugger. As in, each current_node that I expected to be there at some point was. But the node had the "wrong" parent. So there's way for me to actually check if the nodes are being traversed in the right order. And it also makes `trace` not work (as mentioned before).

Also, I'm new to C++ / debugging in general. So I'm not sure how to read the output of it yet.

Comment: `bool Node::operator<` is incorrect most probably.

Comment: @ColinKennedy _"Also, I'm new to C++ / debugging in general. So I'm not sure how to read the output of it yet."_ That's an essential skill you should adopt as quickly as possible.

Comment: @S.M. I used `operator<` for the `std::set` in `trace` but I could re-use `path`. I tried that out but no dice (`operator==` should be okay). Can you think of any other likely issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructor body is totally messed up, you are reading from member `this->parent` which is always initialized to `nullptr` (by the *brace-or-equal-initializer*).

```
 Node(int row, int column, Node *parent) : row(row), column(column)
 {
    if (this->parent != nullptr && *this->parent == *this) {
        throw "Node cannot be parented to itself";
    }

    this->parent = parent;
}
```

Second major problem, this is passing a reference to an object `current_node` whose lifetime is insufficient:

```
auto children = get_children(current_node, graph);
```

By the time you read any of the "children" out of the list, the node pointed to by their `parent` member has already been destroyed.

The copy in `closed_list` would survive, but that can't be used to store a `parent` pointer either, because of the iterator invalidation rules for `std::vector`.  If you change `closed_list` to `std::list<Node>` then the element addresses would be stable.

But then when `a_star` returns all the objects pointed to by instance `parent` pointers will die anyway.  `trace(current_node)` results in a collection of nodes whose `parent` members point outside the collection.

Your best bet is probably to preallocate enough Node objects for the whole `graph` instance, use an index instead of a pointer as parent, and update the `parent` member instead of setting it during construction.  Index values, unlike pointers, remain meaningful no matter how many times a data structure is copied.

(Also, string literals make bad exception objects)

Comment: Ah yes, that's a big mistake. It should be just `parent == this`, yeah? I'll give that a shot. I was under the assumption that the constructor is called during `children.push_back` but now I'll double-check it in the debugger.

Comment: The `*this->parent` is also wrong later in the same line.

Comment: @ColinKennedy: `push_back` only uses a copy constructor.  Although now I see the line that does construct a `Node` with three arguments as the parameter to `push_back`.  (You should be using `emplace_back` to avoid the unnecessary copy)

Comment: @ColinKennedy: Found (probably) your issue, edited to explain.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions (1. converting closed_list to a std::list and using that as parents, 2. creating a Graph of Node objects and using indices as parents to refer to them). Both methods work! You were right about `get_children` as well. Thank you so much! Also `emplace_back` is a great tip. I should really re-read the STL containers to make sure I know them better.